# How to access the project properties from within a class in gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have the following in a gradle build file, what I am trying to do is filter the content of the files before I copy them, so I created a custom filter class which would be called each time a file is copied. Now I am trying to access the project properties from `MyFilter` class, for example I tried to print the `profile` property, but I did not find a way to do that so far, can this be done?

Usually I would pass the profile when starting the build file with `gradlew build -Pprofile=prd`, still I really don't see a way to access those properties from `MyFilter` class.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
tasks.build.finalizedBy('copyFiles')

class MyFilter extends FilterReader  {


    MyFilter(Reader input) {
        super(new StringReader(""))
        //tried many things to print the profile property, nothing worked.
    }
    }
def profile = project.properties['profile'] ?: "dev"
def amqa = project.properties['amqa'] ?: "127.0.0.1"
def amqaEG = project.properties['amqaEG'] ?: "127.0.0.1"

task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
project.properties['amqa']
    from ('config')
    into ('.')
    include('**/*_#' + profile + '*')
    rename { filename ->
        filename.replace '_#' + profile, ''
    }

filter MyFilter

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend [BaseParamFilterReader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/BaseParamFilterReader.java#BaseParamFilterReader), then you get parameters in `setParameters(final Parameter[] parameters)` method.

`Copy` task has `filter` overload that takes parameters, for example:

`filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: '2.3.1'])`

You'd probably write something like

`filter(MyFilter, profile: profile)`

Investigating [`ReplaceTokens`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.7.1/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.java) might help